# Case sensitive in xPath

Tags: xml, xpath, case-sensitive

I am trying to get a list of URLs from a an XML. The URLs are in mixed case. I have tried the code below (xPath 1.0 unfortunately).

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="xpath1">document($fullSitemapDoc)/root/url[contains(loc,$fldr)]</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="translate($xpath1, $uppercase, $smallcase)">
```

And I am getting an error
    Expression does not return a DOM node. -->translate($xpath1, $uppercase, $smallcase)<--

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate an XPath expression as a string in this way. (Well, if you really need to, some products have an xx:evaluate() extension to enable it).

Instead you need to do something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="document(...)/root/url
      [contains(translate(loc, $uppercase, $lowercase)), 
                translate($fldr, $uppercase, $lowercase))]"/>
```

Comment: I used 

`<!--xsl:variable name="lowercase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="document(...)/root/url[contains(translate(loc, $uppercase, $lowercase)), translate($fldr, $uppercase, $lowercase))]"/>`

That did not work. But this code will work to find one state of the fldr.

`<xsl:for-each select="document($fullDocRoot)/root/sitemap/loc">`